# How to troubleshoot Inline Image Transform when there is no error logged?

Tags: image-transforms, logs

Having some odd issues in 2.5 with image transforms (apparently). They are defined in the template, and saved to a Rackspace Cloud Files container. Often, we are getting a 500 Internal Server Error when loading the page or doing a live preview, and nothing about the error is logged anywhere. Trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this. Happens on our production (apache) server, not seeing it on my dev/MAMP machine.

We do have this set in general config:

```
'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,
```

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04 and has ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16

The dev machine (which will transform the images just fine) is running MAMP and does NOT have ImageMagick installed (it does use GD though).

Comment: Are you hosted with Rackspace as well? Is it a Craft generated error or a "plain" one? Could be PHP running out of memory or permissions issue, hard to say. But it should be logged in Apache's error log (or PHP FPM) somewhere, you may have to dig around a bit, that'll give you the file name that's causing it.

Comment: Yeah the site is also Rackspace  (Cloud Server). Don't think it's a permissions issue since the error is sporadic. I'm going to try setting ```'phpMaxMemoryLimit' => '1024M',```

Comment: If it's not in Craft's log files, then it's an Apache generated error.  Have you checked the Apache error logs?

Comment: Nope, nothing in apache error log. This is like a needle in a haystack.

Comment: The kicker is, it seems to only happen on CERTAIN image assets. And we can't tell what is so different about them. File size doesn't seem to be an indicator. The original dimensions are consistent with other images using the same transforms without issue. Even tried re-uploading the image with a different name, after re-saving from photoshop -- the image transform still fails for it.

Comment: I am also getting this issue too. Nothing in nginx/php error logs, nothing in the craft logs. only on new assets that are uploaded to craft, also only appears as a logged in user on templates & in the backend.
Logged out guest users get the images fine.

Comment: @user1463467- interesting.... I haven't even tried to see if being logged in affected it. Does it happen for every new asset you try, or just some?

Comment: welp, that didn't seem to matter in my situation. hurm.

Comment: At this point I'm wondering if it's just caused by a corrupt image that is uploaded. In which case, shouldn't there be an error logged somewhere?

Comment: forcing GD as the image driver on the production site causes the image transforms to work. That's not optimal though, as we'll want to eventually transform pngs... Does Craft log ImageMagick errors somewhere?